# How to split words of sentence based on space using jQuery and fill each word in different input field?

Tags: jquery

I am new to HTML and jQuery. If I paste the long text to the first input, I wanted it to be automatically split to another input (based on space). Is it possible to do it in jQuery?

This is the code:

https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-boyd-jnig1b?file=/index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- if type this long text to first input ,
      Split long text to each input 
      based on space -->

    work pork dork bark crack shame
    <br />
    <input class="input" />

    <input class="input" />

    <input class="input" />
    <input class="input" />
    <input class="input" />
    <input class="input" />
  </body>
  <script>
    // A $( document ).ready() block.
    $(document).ready(function () {});
  </script>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean "split based on space?" How much space do you want to allot to each input field?

Comment: for example this is the text i paste  "work pork dork bark crack shame" each of them got space i wanted to split it, work will come to first input pork to second input same as others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Split your input text based upon space.
2. Loop between them to get each word on text box.

Example:

```js
$(".input").keyup(function() {
  var arr = $(this).val().split(" ");
  $.each(arr, function(index, value) {
    $('input').eq(index).val(value)
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
work pork dork bark crack shame

<input class="input" />
<input class="input" />
<input class="input" />
<input class="input" />
<input class="input" />
<input class="input" />
```

Comment: This sets the handler on *all* input fields, which doesn't seem like what OP was asking for. It also uses the "keyup" event, not the paste event.

Comment: OP already accept answer ,  and answer fulfill requirement. Some time non English user led them no where. Any way I like your answer .

Answer (score 1):

Set up a "paste" handler on the first input field. It splits the string value into an array, then cycles through the other input fields and updates their values with the next array element.

```js
// A $( document ).ready() block.
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input:first-of-type').on('paste', function() {
        let words = $(this).val().split(/\s+/);
        $('input:not(:first-of-type)').each(function(e){
            $(this).val(words[e])
        })
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- if type this long text to first input ,
      Split long text to each input 
      based on space -->

    work pork dork bark crack shame
    <br />
    <input class="input" />

    <input class="input" />

    <input class="input" />
    <input class="input" />
    <input class="input" />
    <input class="input" />
  </body>
</html>
```